# How do I run a selenium web scraping script on loop and send the results to mongodb

Tags: node.js, selenium

I have several selenium scripts that scrape websites on the web, I need these scripts to run every 10 minutes automatically and then send the results to my mongodb database, I know how to send and store data in the database, but I don't get how you run the scripts automatically every x amount of time, and then update your database without you having to do anything?

The backend uses node, express and mongoose. This is what I tried...

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const WebScript = require('../Scripts/WebScript.js')

router.get('/script/web-script', async (req, res) => {
  const results = await WebScript.Script()
  console.log(results)
}

module.exports = router
```

The script runs if I call the route on my localhost, but otherwise it doesn't start automatically. I've set up a server.js that is connected to my mongodb database and I've set up a schema to store the results in mongodb. 'console.log(results)' returns the scraped data like I want it to, but I just can't figure out how to run this automatically when I start the server, and also make it run every 10 minutes after as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

#### Use a pinger

Pingers are basically robots that visit your site (usually to keep your site from sleeping) every set amount of time. A good choice is [Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com/). Since the script executes everytime you visit the site, this will work perfectly.

#### Use setTimeout

Set a simple timer in JavaScript:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   // Run your script here
}, 1000 * 60 * 10); // Milliseconds for 10 minutes
```